# Why is my variable getting initialized in Debug mode, but not in Release mode?

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I have a windows form application built using VC++ dot net 3.
There is a integer variable say int x.

When I run the application in debug mode the value for x =0;
But when I run the application without debugging the value is huge 113901996.

The variable is initialzed as int x = 0

Why is this so? Some setting I need to check?

Comment: Simply post some code please and all will probably become clear.

Comment: Some updates please? Have you tried outputting the variable to `cout` and got the same results? I put some effort into my answer, I'd appreciate some feedback.

Comment: Hi Luchian, Actually, even though I had initialised x, the value of x was being assigned by another function call. Inside this function the variable being returned was not initialised. So if certain condition was not met, the variable not got assigned. Like you said, in debug mode, the variable was on heap and I could see the value, but in release mode, it never existed, hence I was getting  random value returned. Once I initialised the variable in the function, the value were as expected. I really appreciate you taking time off and replying, and sorry about the late reply

Comment: Actually, if you were returning the variable from the method, then it did exist.  Despite all the bickering, my answer is correct - you didn't initialise correctly.  Nothing to do with it being optimised away.  This is summed up with, "the variable being returned was not initialised".  That means it's an initialisation problem, not an optimisation problem.  The variable did exist and was allocated.

Comment: You can't be sure of that, unless you post some assembly. You're not the compiler. You just assume it does any of that based on your intuition. "if you were returning the variable from the method, then it did exist" - really? Can you provide a standard extract to back that up? Variables can be optimized away, just like I've **proven** in my answer (note, proven by binary code). Just because you wrote it down in the code doesn't mean it must exist in the binary.

Comment: You could prove that 1+1=2 in your answer, but just like your optimisation idea, it's not relevant.  The crux: If you return a variable from a function, then it MUST exist.  The fact that it has a large seemingly-random value backs this up - if the variable didn't exist and wasn't uninitialised then where did that value come from?  It clear did exist, and was uninitialised.  As a local variable, it would have gained whatever value happened to be on that part of the stack.  Given your theory, where did 113901996 come from?

Comment: There is more than one way of passing values other than through variables. See my answer, look for the "x isn't actually generated, but rather the 3 value is put on the stack and printed directly." part.

Comment: And where does the random, uninitialised-looking value get pushed on the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: As per your new info, that you're forgetting to initialize the variable, the behavior is expected. You're reading garbage memory.

Now, even if you did initialize the variable, you could still replicate this behavior by not using it in a manner that affects the observable behavior of the program. This is what my original answer treated - which I will leave here for future reference.

Are you actually using `x`? If you're just initializing it, the optimizer will most likely exclude the whole thing.

If it's not influencing the **observable behavior** of the program, the optimizer is free to cut anything from the binary.

The watch might also be lying to you, I've seen that happening in Release mode.

Can you post some minimal code that reproduces the problem?

If you test it with some output, i.e. :

```
cout << x;
```

I'm sure you'll see that `x` is `0`.

EDIT:

Just to clear things out:

```
int main()
{
   int x = 0;
   x = 3;
   return 0;
}
```

will translate to (in release mode, with full optimization):

```
00401000  xor         eax,eax 
00401002  ret
```

The variable not only isn't assigned, **it doesn't even exist**; as opposed to the debug version:

```
00411370  push        ebp  
00411371  mov         ebp,esp 
00411373  sub         esp,0CCh 
00411379  push        ebx  
0041137A  push        esi  
0041137B  push        edi  
0041137C  lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh] 
00411382  mov         ecx,33h 
00411387  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
0041138C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 
0041138E  mov         dword ptr [x],0 
00411395  mov         dword ptr [x],3 
0041139C  xor         eax,eax
```

where the variable x is created and assigned twice (see `mov         dword ptr [x],0`  and `mov         dword ptr [x],3` ).

If observable output is modified by the variable, i.e.:

```
int main()
{
   int x = 0;
   x = 3;
   cout << x;
   return 0;
}
```

the generated binary will look like this:

```
00401000  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (40203Ch)] 
00401006  push        3    
00401008  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> 
0040100E  xor         eax,eax
```

see that even with this, `x` isn't actually generated, but rather the `3` value is put on the stack and printed directly.

But the observed behavior in this case is the same, since `3` is printed. To the user, whether the value of `x`, which should be `3`, is printed, or `3` is printed directly, is irrelevant.

#### The bottom line is: if the behavior of the program is not changed by some statements, they are excluded. In your case, the variable `x` is not even created.

Comment: I suspect this is correct; the optimizer is simply eliding the code because it has no observable behavior. The reason why it's actually appearing to be initialized in debug mode is because the debug versions of the CRT initialize memory differently in order to help you catch bugs. This doesn't happen in the release version. Documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx).

Comment: So initializing an int variable as 0 and only declaring it, is the same?

Comment: @xaria that's not the point. The point is that if some code doesn't influence the observable behavior of the program, the generated binary code **can** not contain that part. This is done by the optimizer to reduce binary size and improve speed. So if you're not actually using x in a visible manner, the optimizer can remove it, as if it didn't even exist.

Comment: So if in the sample code: int x; if(condition) x = 10; return 10 If condition is not met, then what will be the value of x? Any random integer?

Comment: @xaria I edited my answer, hope it is clearer now. The value of x is invalid, since x doesn't even exist, as pointed out in my answer.

Comment: I am a little confused with this answer, isn't the point that variables aren't initialised to a default value in Release mode, and only in Debug?  Other optimisation discussion is almost irrelevant?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone what variable should be initialized in release if the variable doesn't even exist? Initialization is not the issue. The discussion is completely relevant.

Comment: @Luchian - there's no code posted, and the OP is asking "why isn't my variable initialised to 0 in Release Mode?".  The only answer is, "because, variables are not initialised to a default value in Release Mode".  [Even if it wasn't optimised away, the variable would not be initialised to 0]

Comment: @KierenJohnstone you are wrong, the OP does initialize the variable. Read the question again.

Comment: This is a great answer, and the edit providing the disassembly is a great addition. Not sure why it wasn't upvoted yet; fixed that now that I have votes to give out again.

Comment: @Cody - this answer is incorrect, as per the OP now that he's initialising his variable it's working as expected.  He was referring to and returning the variable, meaning it couldn't have been optimised away, and it would always have existed.  Luchian, perhaps I could get an apology for repeated battering too?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone you are, again, wrong. I was able to reproduce the situation exactly. You didn't even try what I suggested. THIS is the correct answer. Might I add it's vary childish of you to not acknowledge this is correct, even when demonstrated by hard facts (asm code, test runs).

Comment: @KierenJohnstone I think what's throwing you off is the initialization/non-itialization part. I know it might seem complicated, but bare with me, I'll throw some knowledge your way. Even if a variable is initialized, even if it's not, even if you assign to it n times (like in my example), if it doesn't affect the observed behavior of the program, the compiler is free to optimize it away. Side node... I honestly hope you've been trolling.

Comment: Luchian, you are right - "if it doesn't affect the observed behavior of the program".  Clearly here, a function returning 113901996 is not intended and so such an optimisation would have done that.  This is SO CLEARLY caused by uninitialised memory, as the OP themselves said!  *When they initialised it, it started working* - how could it be any clearer??

Comment: I fail to see how your asm code and test run is relevant - the OP used a separate function, and didn't initialise the variable.  I can't see the part where your code returns a large, seemingly-random value.  Could you point out that bit, or any similarities between the OP's situation for that matter?

Comment: Finally, your answer starts with, "Are you actually using x?".  Turns out, yes, they were.  It was a local variable in a function that was returned.  Optimisation doesn't mean that the variable might get the value 113901996, but initialisation does.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone but my answer is so complete, it even covers that - see this part - If you test it with some output, i.e. : `cout << x;`
I'm sure you'll see that x is 0. The initial question was dealing with an initialized variable, to quote the op "The variable is initialzed as int x = 0". Even with this new piece of info, my answer is still correct. Besides answering the question, I explain a lot more other stuff.

Comment: Now I'm not trying to change you mind on the vote, because it's probably impossible to change it now (SO only lets you change votes in the first 30 minutes after the cast), I'm just trying to teach you something new. You say variables are initialized in debug but not release - this is wrong. You say a variable exists because it is declared - also wrong. We'll all here to learn.

Comment: If the problem is fixed by initialising a variable (it was), then the problem was that it was uninitialised and taking a seemingly random value.  It doesn't get any more clear-cut than that.  I voted you down because based on what the OP is saying, it's entirely misleading.  There is absolutely nothing happening here to do with optimisation.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone so you're downvoting me for giving a legitimate, well-though, documented and tested answer to a question that had its premises wrong? The answer was to a question where variables had been initialized, the new piece of info that they actually weren't came more than 17 hours later.

Comment: I've downvoted it because it's misleading, and you battered the crap out of me, and downvoted me, despite being correct.  The answer might be of high quality (it is), but it is simply wrong.  It no longer answers the question.  The best thing to do would be remove it, as it is so misleading.  Optimisation has no part to play in this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because variables are not initialised to their default value i.e. 0 (if you don't specify an initial value), in Release mode.

It's a way of forcing the user to initialise all their variables.  In C++, you REALLY SHOULD.  Other languages like C# will default to 0/some other default value for you, but in C++, it's up to you.

I believe you have a problem with initialisation.  You say you are assigning an initial value of `0`, however when you measure you're getting 11301996.  Either you're not initialising as you expect (my best guess) or there's a problem with your output/test routine.  Post your code and I'll be happy to help further.

( Edit: Yes indeed, by initialising your variable the problem was fixed.  This does NOT mean the variable was 'optimised away', it clearly was not - the optimiser will NEVER optimise code to return large, random values where zeroes are expected. )

Comment: This is wrong. Where does it say this in the standard? The standard doesn't even know about debug in release mode. My answer is the correct one, it is what's causing the issue.

Comment: Besides, the op is already initializing the value - "The variable is initialzed as int x = 0" so this is clearly not the problem.

Comment: -1 - the answer is wrong. Variables aren't initialized to default values in debug mode, nor in release mode. Try it out and see for yourself.

Comment: I wasn't referring to a standard, I'm talking about the Visual Studio compiler.  A quick google reveals people saying the same thing, "In release mode local variables are not initialized to 0".  I had missed the part about xaria manually setting 0, but equally how do you think they are reading that value without using the variable, and without debugging?

Comment: I urge you to try it out. In debug mode, in Visual Studio, declare a variable x and don't initialize it. Its value will not be 0.

Comment: My answer is pretty clear. I would assume someone with 10k+ reputation would understand that it directly relates to the op's question and answers it in full detail. This is the cause of the problem.

Comment: So how do you suppose they are reading the value of X without a debugger, unless they are using the variable?

Comment: The op doesn't say anything about reading the variable. I'm not talking about those other cases, which don't relate to this. The optimizer is free to do what it pleases. In this case, x is not used, so it is excluded from compilation. In the cases you're talking about, if x is read, it obviously needs to exits.

Comment: Have you even tried what I suggested? I'm a pretty egotistic guy too, but I can admit when I'm wrong and someone else is right when given the proper arguments.

Comment: I'm saying, how do you think it could apply that they are seeing the value "113901996" (the symptom) without using a debugger?  That is the precise case the OP is asking about - they are seeing that value, when not using a debugger.  How does that fit with the variable not being used / referenced?

Comment: @Hans - Ah I see.  I will rephrase to, "not in release mode" rather than "only in debug mode" then.

Comment: How do you know the op is not using a debugger?

Comment: Your last paragraph is also incorrect. When using a debugger, regardless of whether you initialize x or not, in release mode, if x is not used in a manner that affects observed behavior, it will not be created.

Comment: I will not continue this discussion. I would have hoped you'd understand by now, apparently you don't. I can't see how I can make it any more clearer.

Comment: You've been continuing the discussion with yourself for some time.  Here's where the OP says they're not using a debugger: "But when I run the application without debugging the value is huge 113901996.". Ciao

Comment: I'm sure the op means he's not running the debug version. Because if he was printing the value, he would get 0.

Comment: Thanks Luchian your answer helps a lot.